# Converting Multiple PDF files into Text (R Language)

Tags: r, pdf, dplyr, tesseract

I am using the "tesseract" library in R to convert "PDF files into text", like shown over here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tesseract/vignettes/intro.html

```
library(pdftools)
library(tesseract)

pngfile <- pdftools::pdf_convert('myfile_1.pdf', dpi = 600)
text <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile)
cat(text)
```

The above code works perfectly. Now, I am trying to "mass upload" a large number of PDF files and convert them into text- currently, I figured out how to do this manually

```
#import and convert 1st file
   pngfile_1 <- pdftools::pdf_convert('myfile_1.pdf', dpi = 600)
    text_1 <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile_1)

#import and convert 2nd file (note: the files do not have the same naming convention)
   pngfile_2 <- pdftools::pdf_convert('second_file.pdf', dpi = 600)
    text_2 <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile_2)

etc
```

I copied/pasted the above code 50 times (while changing the "index", i.e. `pngfile_i, text_i`) and was able to accomplish what I wanted to do. However, I am looking for a somewhat "automatic" to import and convert all the pdf files.

At the moment, all my pdf files are in the following folder:

```
"C:/Users/me/Documents/mypdfs"
```

I found the following code which can be used to "mass import" pdf files into R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)


tbl_fread <- 
    list.files(pattern = "*.pdf") %>% 
    map_df(~fread(.))
```

But I am not sure how to instruct this code to import all pdf's from the correct directory (`"C:/Users/me/Documents/mypdfs"`). I also don't know how to instruct R to "rename" each imported pdf as "pdf_1, pdf_2, etc."

If all the pdf files were correctly imported and created, I could then write a "loop" and execute the desired commands, e.g.

```
# "n" would be the total number of pdf files 

for (i in 1:n)
{
pngfile_i <- pdftools::pdf_convert('myfile_i.pdf', dpi = 600)
text_i <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile_i)
}
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this question answered yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `full.names = TRUE` in your `list.files`-function, but this assumes that `"C:/Users/me/Documents/mypdfs"` is contained within your `project`.

Alternatively, you can use `path = "Documents/mypdfs` with `full.names = TRUE` which will direct the `path` to `mypdfs`.

```
list.files(
        path = "Documents/mypdfs"
        full.names = TRUE,
        pattern = "*.pdf"
        )
```

To save them according to you `pdf_n` then you can use `paste` along with `map`. Here I used `data.frames` to provide an example, as I do not work with pdfs and have none in bulk that I am willing to process.

```
library(tidyverse)

1:length(tbl_fread) %>% map(
        .f = function(i) {
                
                # Your regular function
                # related to PDF
                
                
                # Saving according to desired names
                write.table(
                        tbl_fread[[i]],
                        file = paste0("pdf_", i, ".csv")
                )
                
                
        }
)
```

To verify it works as intended, we can read it accordingly,

```
read.table(
        file = "pdf_1.csv"
)
```

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: thanks! can I ask - why did you not use a loop in this ?

Comment: Actually, I did use a `for-loop` - it is just wrapped in `map` instead of `for () {}` or `lapply`.